# Moving Angular 4 App to be secured of SSL certificate Error

Tags: angular, ssl, iis

We developed a SPA using angular 4 which is working fine over unsecured channel [http], but after securing the channel over https on IIS we faced an error on all browsers, we have our own domain and a valid certificates one for frontend and another for backend [APIs], but still getting the following error :

[Error,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK53L.png) 
[valid certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqcgy.png)

Request & Response are below [Note that when adding the requested url in the browser address it is working fine]: 
[Request & Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgdji.png)

Comment: Can you share Request and Response Header , you can find them in Network tab of chrome/ mozilla Dev tool.

Comment: Request & Response attached

Comment: By Any Chance have you missed implementing CORS, because it looks like a CORS error.

Comment: I implemented the CORS and working fine with http but after switching to https these errors occured, and if you checked the error, the chrome couldn't load the en.json file which is a frontend resource

Comment: What is this en.json file , I mean is it some kind of an Environment variable or an application variable file??

Comment: It is a json file used as localization file (En means English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem, Which is I am using the "Authorization" header in requests, but before the user login to a system, the value of authorization is empty and still my system send this header (Authorization) with empty value which is prevented by the browsers, so there are two solutions :

1. Is to not send this attribute (Authorization) at header if the value is empty
2. Use another attribute to keep the user token